# The scope of the variable can be reduced in a function in c

Tags: c, warnings, cppcheck

So i have this function and it doesnt matter what it does what matters is that im using cppcheck to check on errors and i get this message:

message:

```
(style) The scope of the variable 'i' can be reduced. Warning: Be careful when fixing this message, especially when there are inner loops. Here is an example where cppcheck will write that the scope for 'i' can be reduced:
void f(int x)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (x) {
        // it's safe to move 'int i = 0;' here
        for (int n = 0; n < 10; ++n) {
            // it is possible but not safe to move 'int i = 0;' here
            do_something(&i);
        }
    }
}
When you see this message it is always safe to reduce the variable scope 1 level.
```

Function:

```
void p(int idp, int price)
{
   int i = 0;
   if ((indentify_prod(sistem,idp) == 1) && (price > 0)) /* product exists in the sistem*/
   {
      sistem[idp].price = price;
      while (i <500)
      {
          if (sistem[idp].ident == sistem_orders[i].set_prod[idp].ident)
          {
              if ((product_in_order(i,sistem_orders,idp) == 1) && (product_in_system(idp) == 1)){
              sistem_orders[i].set_prod[idp].price = price;
              }
          }
          i++;
      }
   }
   else 
   {
      printf("Impossivel alterar preco do produto %d. Produto inexistente.\n",idp);
   }
}
```

I really dont understand this warning like reduce the scope what does this mean? Ive tried to reduce the value of 500 to 200, but it still gives the same error and i dont understand why.

Seriously any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It just means you can move the deceleration of i within the scope of the if statement

Comment: The word "scope" refers to where the variable is declared and is valid to use. As others have said, you can move the declaration of the variable "i" inside the "if" statement, so that it is valid only within the "if" block but not after. It is generally considered good to make the scope of variables only as large as is necessary. This helps the compiler understand how to optimize the program, and helps code maintainers understand how you intend to use the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Simple example:

```
void foo()
{
  int somevar;
  for (int j = 0; j < bar; j++)
  {
    // do something with somevar
  }

  // more code not using somevar
}
```

You can rewrite this like this:

```
void foo()
{
  for (int j = 0; j < bar; j++)
  {
    int somevar;  // you can declare somevar here because it's
                  // not used outside the scope of this for loop

    // do something with somevar
  }

  // more code not using somevar
}
```

Comment: This does not match OP’s code. In their code, `i` persists throughout the execution of the `for` or `while` loop; its first use is in the first iteration of the loop, its last use is in the last iteration of the loop, and those uses and all between them refer to the same object, with one lifetime. In the code in this answer, `somevar` is instantiated in each iteration, and each iteration uses a different object with a different lifetime. The OP can move the definition of `i` inside the `if` but not inside the body of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can move it inside the `if` to reduce the scope of `i`.

```
void p(int idp, int price)
{
>>>int i = 0; ***** REMOVE THIS LINE *****
   if ((indentify_prod(sistem,idp) == 1) && (price > 0)) /* product exists in the sistem*/
   {
>>>>>>int i = 0; ***** ADD THIS LINE *****
      sistem[idp].price = price;
      while (i <500)
      {
          if (sistem[idp].ident == sistem_orders[i].set_prod[idp].ident)
          {
              if ((product_in_order(i,sistem_orders,idp) == 1) && (product_in_system(idp) == 1)){
              sistem_orders[i].set_prod[idp].price = price;
              }
          }
          i++;
      }
   }
   else 
   {
      printf("Impossivel alterar preco do produto %d. Produto inexistente.\n",idp);
   }
}
```